# Multiple forms, one click, post all forms' inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let's say i have multiple forms in one page. The user can submit these forms one by one. But user wants post all these forms' inputs by just one button(like phpmyadmin interface). How can solve this problem?

Comment: by providing the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you posting that using ajax?

Comment: It is possible by using AJAX. Not by normal form POST.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use normal HTML forms to do this, but however, you can solve this issue using AJAX and submitting each request individually, asynchronously. For eg., say you have three forms here:

```
<form action="url1.php" id="frm1">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
<form action="url2.php" id="frm2">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
</form>
<form action="url3.php" id="frm3">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
```

And in the AJAX Call, for now, am using jQuery:

```
$(".submitAll").click(function(){
  $("form").each(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize());
  });
});
```

Comment: Or you can combine all forms' data in one request provided your PHP will handle all forms on the server-side.

Comment: or you can create hidden forms and fire them via javascript

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting?

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted. But I think, if you replace `$(this).serialize()` with `$('form').serialize()` you can get all forms' data in one call and avoid the foreach and different calls. Then you can process all data server side.

Comment: @Ramy That would be wrong. If I do that, all the form data will go to one single URL, which is not the right one. I am saying here, if there are three different forms with different inputs and different URLs, this would be the best method!

Comment: Agreed. I was just saying that, If I have the choice IMHO, I will post everything to the server in one call then handle the different forms at the server side. rather than different calls. But if you need to send it to different URLs then your was is the best method. :)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work... it should at least get you started on the right track. 
With jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){ 

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    formData = []; 

    $("form").each(function(){

        formData.push($(this).serializeArray());

    });


    $.ajax({

        url: "yourProcessingScript.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success:function(response){

            alert("Success, probably - ! ");

        } 

     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without ajax, however it's a bit tricky. Put the submit button in a separate `<form>`, and you can just copy all the form data across upon clicking on the submit button.

```
<?php
    $result = (isset($_POST)) ? $_POST : "";
?>

<!-- Your forms -->
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="a" />
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="b" />
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="c" />
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" class="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="d" />
</form>

<!-- Target form -->
<form action="" method="POST" id="submit-form">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<pre><?php print_r($result); ?></pre>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {
            inputs = $(".myForm input");
            inputs.each(function(index) {
                $(inputs[index]).clone(true).appendTo("#submit-form").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g6ba-iyqn